# Largest disc centered at $z_0$ in which $f$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, holomorphic-functions

$$f(z) = \frac{az + b}{cz + d}, \quad \text{ for } a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{C}$$

We have that  $f \in H(\mathbb{C} - \{ z = -\frac{d}{c} \} )$.

My notes say that for any point $z_0$ in the plane, except $-\frac{d}{c}$, $f$ is holomorphic in the open disc centred at $z_0$ with radius $\mid z_0 + \frac{d}{c} \mid$.

Why is that?

Comment: you have already observe that the function is holomorphic at all points except for $z=-d/c$. Then, $|z_0+\frac{d}{c}|=|z_0-(-d/c)|$ is the distance from $z_0$ to the nearest point that is not in the domain. If you put the radius larger the point $z=-d/c$ will creep into the disc.

Comment: A more interesting observation is that it is analytic (equal to the values of a power series that converges) on that disc. Is that what you are asking?